# Angular Formly Custom Template ng-click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-formly

I'm attempting to register an ng-click event using a custom template to display items in an accordion but they do not get registered at all. I've tried everything, using a hideExpression/watcher, putting the ng-click event in the template, using ng-class/ng-init/ng-click to set the element to active, etc...nothing has worked. Even put an onClick function in the templateOptions. Still no luck...
It almost seems like the items are there but they are not there...never have had such an issue with getting a simple click to work.  Basically I want the user to be able to click an item, and then that item becomes active and updates the model with the selection, while the previous item becomes inactive...I've got a very simple piece of jQuery code that works in other things but is not working here...

At my wit's end as to why any of these ways haven't worked...please help...

Here is the plunker;

http://plnkr.co/edit/d5kHjH?p=preview

```
 template: '<a li class="list-group-item small" ng-click="active = !active" ng-init="active = true""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>   {{to.label}}</li></a>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with a few changes...

```
template: `<div ng-init= "active = false">
  <label class="list-group-item small" onclick="$('.list-group-item').removeClass('active'); $(this).addClass('active')" ng-click="updateModel()" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>   {{to.label}}</label>
  </div>`,
```